# Print list item index, from index of another list

Tags: python, list, max, pycharm, min

This is the code I have so far, with proper indentation but I don't know how to do it on here. I am trying to print the month with the max and min rainfall, but so far I am only printing the index of the max/min rain. E.g. I am trying to print: `'Highest rainfall: 45 mm in January'`, and `'Lowest rainfall: 12 mm in March'`. But so far I am just printing `'Highest rainfall: 2 (index of max in rain)'`, rather than the month.

```
def main():  
    rains = []  
    months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']  
    for month in range(12):  
       rain = eval(input('Enter the amount of rain for ' + months[month] + ': '))  
       rains.append(rain)  
    total = sum(rains)  
    average = (total/len(rains))  
    print()  
    print('The Rain Amounts:')  
    print(rains)  
    print()  
    print('Total Rainfall:', (round(total,2)), 'mm.')  
    print('Average Rainfall:', (round(average,2)),'mm.')  
    print('Highest rainfall:', rains.index(max(rains)), 'mm in', months.index(rains.index(max(rains))))  
    print('Lowest rainfall:', rains.index(min(rains)), 'mm in', months.index(rains.index(min(rains))))  

main()
```

Comment: All code must be indented 4 spaces (beyond whatever indent the line normally has) to get treated as a "code block."

Comment: It is better to use `int(input())` intead of `eval(input())`.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
import operator   

months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
rains = [12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 4, 2, 1]  

index, value = max(enumerate(rains), key=lambda p: p[1])
print "Month with max rain: " + months[index]
index, value = min(enumerate(rains), key=lambda p: p[1])
print "Month with min rain: " + months[index]
```

Output:

```
Month with max rain: January
Month with min rain: December
```

[Live demo](http://goo.gl/xsftTb).

Answer (score 0):

```
max_rain = max(rains)
max_rain_months = [months[i] for i,amt in enumerate(rains) if amt == max_rain]
print("Highest rainfall:", max_rain, "mm in", ', '.join(max_rain_months))
```

Similar for `min`.